# Calling another scenario by tag in karate feature file is not recongnizing the karate-config.js function

Tags: karate

Make a new feature file test.feature as below

```
Feature: Test bug

  @first
  Scenario: Test first
    * getValue()
    * karate.call('test.feature@second')

  @second
  Scenario: Test Second
    * getValue()
```

Now go to karate-config.js and make below function

```
function getValue() {
    karate.log('hello');
    karate.log('excuted this function')
}
```

Now run your first scenario by right click on scenario, you will see that the function is getting recognized by 1st scenario but not getting recognized by second scenario

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are calling `karate.call('myFeature.feature@newCheck')` inside `karate-config.js` right after you have defined our `myJsMethodCall()` as `config.myJsMethodCall` ?

If so, you have to pass `config` as the second parameter so that `myJsMethodCall()` will be available in the scope of the called feature

```
karate.call('myFeature.feature@newCheck', config)
```

Note: variables declared in `karate-config.js` will be available to the features only after completion of it evaluation.